# Remove .php extension and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like remove extesion .php and at the same time add /404

I've watched several codes to remove .php, however to remove but adds server paths in the url

```
I have: http://domain.com/pages/header.php
I want: http://domain.com/pages/header or http://domain.com/pages/header/404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^header/404$ header.php [L]
```

put this in pages directory.